# Market not Managed error (3) in beta app

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm just getting crazy...

My app is still in beta version. I'm trying to test the license part before publish it. But I still keep receiving `ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED` answer. My e-mail is already in `Developer Console` (**Settings > License Testing**), the answer is set to `LICENSED`, and I verified my public key like thousands times. This is my code:

```
callback = new DfmLicenseCheckerCallback(this, progress);           

AESObfuscator obfuscator = new AESObfuscator(SALT, this.getPackageName(), Unique.GetKey());
ServerManagedPolicy policy = new ServerManagedPolicy(this, obfuscator); 
checker = new LicenseChecker(this, policy, appKey);

checker.checkAccess(callback);
```

Comment: are you using the emulator or real phone? are you using your development email?

Comment: Real phone... The e-mail is the same, but the other google accounts that I have in my phone are in tests list...

Comment: Try to load your apk for production instead of beta but without publishing it only as draft

Comment: Promote to prod has same effect? I'm really just quitting and publishing it to try to resolve this...

Comment: I don't remember if it has the same effect, maybe. You can try

Comment: Same problem, still getting error 3

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, I read lots of posts saying like 'yeah, works fine to me'

Comment: Are you sure that you are exporting a signed application with your real certificate and not with the debug one?

Comment: I created a keystore for that...

Comment: I can choose the password of keystore and key, right? I don't need to use something from google play, do I?

Comment: Your Unique.GetKey() should return the key you see in your google play developer console

Comment: Unique.GetKey() is in AESObfuscator constructor, in parameter deviceId... I used the Secure.ANDROID_ID in it...

Comment: The public key goes in LicenseChecker, I stored it in appKey in my code

Comment: Oops sorry, yes of course, you're right. I really don't know why it doesn't work for you

Comment: I would like to not be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the problem. Even in BETA you have to publish your app to see its license.

Comment: so you mean to public a beta version?